# Ist dieser Spiegel-Satz richtig?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality, apposition

In der *Spiegel*-Kritik des Films *Vor der Morgenröte* steht:

> Die Schauspielerin, Regisseurin, Drehbuchautorin Maria Schrader hat einen Film über die letzten Jahre Stefan Zweigs gedreht. Den 1934, als er vor den Nazis floh, meistgelesenen deutschsprachigen Autor, Juden, Pazifisten, Österreicher, Textilerben.

Der letzte Satz kommt mir falsch vor: Sollte es nicht heißen:

> **Des** 1934,als er vor den Nazis floh, meistgelesenen deutschsprachigen Autor**s**, Juden, Pazifisten, Österreichers, Textilerben.
>   Welcher Satz ist richtig?

**Klarstellung**
Ich möchte nur wissen ob der Spiegeltext richtig ist.
Man kann ihn natürlich in unendlich vielen Arten modifizieren/verbessern aber um solche Änderungen handelt es in meiner Frage nicht.

Comment: Ich hätte jetzt spontan "dem" benutzt, aber ohne irgendeine triftige grammatikalische Begründung.

Comment: @Gerhard Kein Wunder, dass Du keine triftige Begründung findest, denn ein Dativ hier hier ja nun mal komplett falsch ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mir kommt das auch nicht korrekt vor.

Wäre der zweite Satz ein zum eigenständigen Satz erhobener Relativsatz, dann müsste es meiner Meinung nach

> die letzten Jahre Stefan Zweigs, **des** 1934 ... meistgelesenen ... Autor**s** ...

heißen, denn es wurde kein Film über *Stefan Zweig, den 1934 ... meistgelesenen Autor ...* geschrieben (Akkusativ), sondern über *die letzten Jahre Stefan Zweigs*, also Genitiv.

Mir scheint es so, als habe der Autor zunächst geschrieben:

> Die Schauspielerin, Regisseurin, Drehbuchautorin Maria Schrader hat einen Film über Stefan Zweig gedreht. Den 1934, als er vor den Nazis floh, meistgelesenen deutschsprachigen Autor, Juden, Pazifisten, Österreicher, Textilerben.

Und dann später den Satz präzisiert zu

> Die Schauspielerin, Regisseurin, Drehbuchautorin Maria Schrader hat einen Film über **die letzten Jahre Stefan Zweigs** gedreht. Den 1934, als er vor den Nazis floh, meistgelesenen deutschsprachigen Autor, Juden, Pazifisten, Österreicher, Textilerben.

Comment: Danke für Deine Erklärung und Vermutung, Thorsten: sie sind sehr überzeugend.

Answer (score 6):

Das passt schon so. Der zweite Satz ist nur eine Verkürzung als Folge einer literarischen Freiheit, die sich der Autor genehmigt hat. Fügt man ein zweites »über« ein, und verbindet die beiden Sätze, dann wird es vielleicht klarer:

> Die Schauspielerin, Regisseurin, Drehbuchautorin Maria Schrader hat einen Film über die letzten Jahre Stefan Zweigs gedreht; **über** den 1934, als er vor den Nazis floh, meistgelesenen deutschsprachigen Autor, Juden, Pazifisten, Österreicher, Textilerben.

Ich persönlich würde auch die beiden Kommata vor der Drehbuchautorin und dem Textilerben durch ein »und« ersetzen, aber der Autor des Artikels hat, offenbar um intellektueller zu wirken, sich gleich an mehreren Stellen einer etwas individuelleren Grammatik befleißigt.

Comment: Ein "über" einzufügen, führt zu einer ziemlich holprigen Wortverdopplung. Allerdings würde es den verwendeten Akkusativ rechtfertigen.

Answer (score 1):

m.E. nach ist der Relativsatz zu einem eigenen Satz erhoben worden. So scheint er mir falsch. Richtig könnte er, wenn ich den Inhalt richtig verstehe, heißen:

> Die Schauspielerin, Regisseurin, Drehbuchautorin Maria Schrader hat einen Film über die letzten Jahre Stefan Zweigs gedreht, der 1934 als  meistgelesener deutschsprachiger Autor, Jude, Pazifist, Österreicher, Textilerbe vor den Nazis floh.

Eine Variante in zwei Sätzen ist z.B.:

> Die Schauspielerin, Regisseurin, Drehbuchautorin Maria Schrader hat einen Film über die letzten Jahre Stefan Zweigs gedreht. Der meistgelesene deutschsprachige Autor, Jude, Pazifist, Österreicher, Textilerbe floh 1934 vor den Nazis.

Comment: Ich sehe dasselbe Problem mit Deinem Satz: da *Stefan Zweigs*  im Genitiv steht sollte es, meiner Meinung nach, heißen: *des meistgelesenen Autors*

Comment: Ja, Dein zweiter, editierter,  Satz ist natürlich korrekt aber meine Frage war, ob der Spiegel Satz richtig ist.

Comment: Du hast Recht mit dem Genitiv, ich hatte die Relativkonstruktion im Sinn und den Satz entsprechend editiert. Sry :)

Comment: Hier hat sich offensichtlich jemand im Dschungel seines eigenen überkomplizierten Satzbaus verirrt. Solche Fehler geschehen erfahrungsgemäß oft nicht beim ursprünglichen Autor, sondern beim schludrigen Korrekturlesen. Die beste Lösung ist sicher die von dir vorgeschlagene Auftrennung in zwei vollständige Sätze.

Comment: Hier ist kein "Relativsatz" gewesen, sondern eine Apposition, die normalerweise mit Komma abgetrennt wird, in diesem Fall aber mit einem Punkt, um z.B. den Satz für den Leser verdaulicher zu machen oder um die in der Apposition enthaltenen Information in einem Kontext hervorzuheben. Das kann als journalistischer Stil angesehen werden. Das als 'falsch' zu bezeichnen, wäre etwas zu rigide gedacht.

Comment: @Dictionarics Anonymous  Ja, es handelt sich um eine Apposition. Es ist nichtdestoweniger  falsch ( meiner Meinung nach), dass der Artikel *Den* des apposierten Satzes im Akkusativ steht, statt im Genitiv, dem Kasus (...Stefan Zweigs...) im ersten Satz. [Und ich hoffe, dass *meine* Apposition im vorigen Satz korrekt ist :-) ]